# Can all Divide and Conquer algorithms utilize parallelism?

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, divide-and-conquer

I am taking an algorithms class, and it seems to be case that the divide and conquer algorithms can be implemented utilizing parallel processing. Is this always the case?

Comment: Any algorithm *can* be implemented using parallel processing.  The question you really want to ask is whether they *should* be.  IE: Whether there's any benefit to doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not necessarily efficiently.

Divide and conquer algorithms fits best (easier to understand) in task-level parallelism. These tasks are recursive and recursive tasks can be explained as a task tree hierarchy. Task tree hierarchies can be viewed as multiple calls of a function using different parameters. Some function calls will wait upon other executions (ie. its children), which is available in the parallel jargon as a *wait*o or a *join* if executed asynchronously or available directly in synchronous executions (*blocking* calls will wait on results automatically). All of these operations are practically available in every parallel framework.

But communication between parallel tasks can be costly depending on parameter data size. If dividing and distributing your problem in smaller pieces (over network for multiple computers execution or between processes for multicore computing) takes more time than executing the pieces, you won't have a performance gain. You will in fact lose performance.

Converting a serial divide and conquer algorithm to its parallel counterpart is easier using a framework allowing task hierarchies such as OpenMP's tasks in C/C++ or [SCOOP](https://code.google.com/p/scoop/) in Python (many more available).